# Laravel View Downloadable Link Not Working On Live

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in laravel storage, i have added a CSV file, and I have added a downloadable link on view, on my local it works perfectly, but on my live server it says "does not exist"

This is my code

Controller code

```
public function download(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->download(storage_path("app/public/sample_csv_ffq_user_accounts.csv"));
        // return Storage::download('sample_csv_ffq_user_accounts.csv');
        // $destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/excel/sample_csv_ffq_user_accounts.csv');
        // return response()->download($destinationPath);
    }
```

View code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <p style="font-size:15px">Download sample template <a href="{{ route('food_freq.download') }}">here</a></p>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: make sure the public folder has proper permission to write the file, check your server log and share the exact error. We can't figure out what is wrong on your server.

Comment: Have you run ```php artisan storage:link``` on your production env?

Comment: @KurtFriars not yet will try this, 
thank you